# Sitecore 10 installation through Docker gives error

Tags: installation, docker

I am getting an error like this when I am trying to install `Sitecore 10` using `docker` following https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

The error is

```
Cannot start service rendering: container
60ab51345a0dc1aea3113ef4f724c5143c090e3781133ca37c37202332f314c8
encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: failure in a
Windows system call: The virtual machine or container exited
unexpectedly. (0xc0370106)
```

When I tried to view the log then I found the error like this

```
[ApiProxy          ][Error  ] msg="Mount denied:\nThe source path
\"\\\\Self\\\\sitecore10apps\\\\FirstAPP:c:\\\\license:rw\"\ntoo many
colons"
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file is

```
    version: "2.4"
    services:
      traefik:
        isolation: ${TRAEFIK_ISOLATION}
        image: ${TRAEFIK_IMAGE}
        command:
          - "--ping"
          - "--api.insecure=true"
          - "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"
          - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
          - "--providers.file.directory=C:/etc/traefik/config/dynamic"
          - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443"
        ports:
          - "443:443"
          - "8079:8080"
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping"]
        volumes:
          - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
            target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
            type: npipe
          - ./traefik:C:/etc/traefik
        depends_on:
          id:
            condition: service_healthy
          cm:
            condition: service_healthy
      mssql:
        isolation: ${ISOLATION}
        image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-mssql:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        environment:
          SA_PASSWORD: ${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          SITECORE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${SITECORE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
          ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
          SQL_SERVER: mssql
        ports:
          - "14330:1436"
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: .\mssql-data
            target: c:\data
      solr:
        isolation: ${ISOLATION}
        image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}nonproduction/solr:8.4.0-${SITECORE_VERSION}
        ports:
          - "8987:8986"
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: .\solr-data
            target: c:\data
        environment:
          SOLR_MODE: solrcloud
      solr-init:
        isolation: ${ISOLATION}
        image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-solr-init:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        environment:
          SITECORE_SOLR_CONNECTION_STRING: http://solr:8983/solr
          SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME: ${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}
        depends_on:
          solr:
            condition: service_healthy
      id:
        isolation: ${ISOLATION}
        image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-id:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        environment:
          Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__SitecoreMemberShipOptions__ConnectionString: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Core;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__AccountOptions__PasswordRecoveryUrl: https://${CM_HOST}/sitecore/login?rc=1
          Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__PasswordClient__ClientSecrets__ClientSecret1: ${SITECORE_IDSECRET}
          Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__DefaultClient__AllowedCorsOrigins__AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1: https://${CM_HOST}
          Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateRawData: ${SITECORE_ID_CERTIFICATE}
          Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__PublicOrigin: https://${ID_HOST}
          Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateRawDataPassword: ${SITECORE_ID_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
          timeout: 300s
        depends_on:
          mssql:
            condition: service_healthy
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.id-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
          - "traefik.http.routers.id-secure.rule=Host(`${ID_HOST}`)"
          - "traefik.http.routers.id-secure.tls=true"
      cm:
        isolation: ${ISOLATION}
        image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cm:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        depends_on:
          id:
            condition: service_started
          xconnect:
            condition: service_started
        environment:
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Core: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Core;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Security: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Core;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Master: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Master;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Web: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Web;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Messaging;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Pools: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.pools;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Referencedata;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Tasks: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.tasks;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_ExperienceForms: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.ExperienceForms;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Exm.Master: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Exm.master;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Reporting: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Reporting;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Sitecore.Reporting.Client: http://xconnect
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Solr.Search: http://solr:8983/solr;solrCloud=true
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SitecoreIdentity.Secret:  ${SITECORE_IDSECRET}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection: http://xconnect
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Operations.Client: http://xconnect
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Reporting.Client: http://xconnect
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.ReferenceData.Client: http://xconnect
          Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
          Sitecore_Identity_Server_Authority: https://${ID_HOST}
          Sitecore_Identity_Server_InternalAuthority: http://id
          Sitecore_Identity_Server_CallbackAuthority: https://${CM_HOST}
          Sitecore_Identity_Server_Require_Https: "false"
          SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME: ${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}
          MEDIA_REQUEST_PROTECTION_SHARED_SECRET: ${MEDIA_REQUEST_PROTECTION_SHARED_SECRET}
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
          timeout: 300s
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.middlewares.force-STS-Header.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
          - "traefik.http.middlewares.force-STS-Header.headers.stsSeconds=31536000"
          - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
          - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.rule=Host(`${CM_HOST}`)"
          - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.tls=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.middlewares=force-STS-Header"
      xconnect:
        isolation: ${ISOLATION}
        image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xconnect:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        ports:
          - "8081:80"
        depends_on:
          mssql:
            condition: service_healthy
          solr-init:
            condition: service_started
        environment:
          Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Messaging;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Storage: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Storage;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Reporting: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Reporting;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Marketingautomation: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Marketingautomation;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Pools: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.pools;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Referencedata;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Collection: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SolrCore: http://solr:8983/solr/${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}_xdb;solrCloud=true
          Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:CollectionSearch:Services:Solr.SolrReaderSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
          Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:CollectionSearch:Services:XConnectSolrHealthCheckServicesConfiguration:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
          Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrReaderSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
          Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrWriterSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
          timeout: 300s
      xdbsearchworker:
        isolation: ${ISOLATION}
        image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xdbsearchworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        depends_on:
          xconnect:
            condition: service_healthy
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Collection: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SolrCore: http://solr:8983/solr/${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}_xdb;solrCloud=true
          Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
          Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrReaderSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
          Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrWriterSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
          Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:CollectionSearch:Services:XConnectSolrHealthCheckServicesConfiguration:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1 -Port 8080"]
          timeout: 300s
      xdbautomationworker:
        isolation: ${ISOLATION}
        image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xdbautomationworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        depends_on:
          xconnect:
            condition: service_healthy
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection: http://xconnect
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Marketingautomation: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Marketingautomation;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Referencedata;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Messaging;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1 -Port 8080"]
          timeout: 300s
      cortexprocessingworker:
        isolation: ${ISOLATION}
        image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cortexprocessingworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        depends_on:
          xconnect:
            condition: service_healthy
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Storage: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Storage;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Tasks: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Tasks;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection: http://xconnect
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Configuration: http://xconnect
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Search: http://xconnect
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Messaging;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Reporting: Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Reporting;User ID=sa;Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
          Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1 -Port 8080"]
          timeout: 300s


My docker-compose.override.yml is

#
# The docker-compose.yml in this solution is a stock Sitecore XP0 environment, without
# any changes. This override represents all the additions/changes needed for this solution.
# Note that some of the overrides point to 'empty' Dockerfiles. This is recommended, even if
# you are not customizing an image, to enable retagging and later customization. See Sitecore
# Containers documentation for details.
#

version: "2.4"

services:

  # A servercore image with both the netcore and netframework SDKs.
  # See Dockerfile for more details.
  dotnetsdk:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-dotnetsdk:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/dotnetsdk
    scale: 0

  # The solution build image is added here so it can be referenced as a build dependency
  # for the images which use its output. Setting "scale: 0" means docker-compose will not
  # include it in the running environment. See Dockerfile for more details.
  solution:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-solution:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        BUILD_CONFIGURATION: ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION}
        BUILD_IMAGE: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-dotnetsdk:${VERSION:-latest}
    depends_on:
      - dotnetsdk
    scale: 0

  # This is our custom image for an ASP.NET Core Rendering Host.
  # If target is 'debug', it will use the SDK image as parent and run 'dotnet watch.'
  # Otherwise, it's a standard ASP.NET Core container. See Dockerfile for details.
  rendering:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-rendering:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/rendering
      target: ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION}
      args:
        DEBUG_PARENT_IMAGE: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-dotnetsdk:${VERSION:-latest}
        SOLUTION_IMAGE: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-solution:${VERSION:-latest}
    volumes:
      - .\:C:\solution
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "http://*:80"
      # These values add to/override ASP.NET Core configuration values.
      # See rendering host Startup for details.
      Sitecore__InstanceUri: "http://cm"
      Sitecore__RenderingHostUri: "https://${RENDERING_HOST}"
      Sitecore__EnableExperienceEditor: "true"
    depends_on:
      - solution
      - cm
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.rendering-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.rendering-secure.rule=Host(`${RENDERING_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.rendering-secure.tls=true"

  # Mount the Traefik configuration and certs.
  traefik:
    volumes:
      - ./docker/traefik:C:/etc/traefik
    depends_on:
      - rendering

  # Mount our SQL data folder and use our custom image with the Headless Services (JSS)
  # module data added. See Dockerfile for details.
  mssql:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-mssql:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/mssql
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-mssql:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE: ${HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE}
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .\docker\data\sql
        target: c:\data

  # Some modules (like SXA) also require additions to the Solr image.
  solr:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .\docker\data\solr
        target: c:\data

  # Mount our Solr data folder and use our retagged Solr image.
  # Some modules (like SXA) also require additions to the Solr image.
  solr-init:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-solr-init:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/solr-init
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-solr-init:${SITECORE_VERSION}

  # Use our retagged Identity Server image.
  # Configure for a mounted license file instead of using SITECORE_LICENSE.
  id:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-id:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/id
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-id:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_LICENSE_FOLDER}:c:\license
    environment:
      SITECORE_LICENSE_LOCATION: c:\license\license.xml

  # Use our custom CM (XP0 Standalone) image with added modules and solution code.
  # Folders are mounted below for code deployment and log output. See Dockerfile for details.
  # Configure for a mounted license file instead of using SITECORE_LICENSE.
  cm:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-cm:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/cm
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cm:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        SOLUTION_IMAGE: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-solution:${VERSION:-latest}
        TOOLS_IMAGE: ${TOOLS_IMAGE}
        MANAGEMENT_SERVICES_IMAGE: ${MANAGEMENT_SERVICES_IMAGE}
        HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE: ${HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - solution
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_DEPLOY_PATH}\platform:C:\deploy
      - ${LOCAL_DATA_PATH}\cm:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs
      - ${HOST_LICENSE_FOLDER}:c:\license
    environment:
      SITECORE_LICENSE_LOCATION: c:\license\license.xml
      RENDERING_HOST_PUBLIC_URI: "https://${RENDERING_HOST}"
      ## Development Environment Optimizations
      SITECORE_DEVELOPMENT_PATCHES: DevEnvOn,CustomErrorsOff,DebugOn,DiagnosticsOff,InitMessagesOff,RobotDetectionOff
      Sitecore_AppSettings_exmEnabled:define: "no" # remove to turn on EXM
    entrypoint: powershell.exe -Command "& C:\tools\entrypoints\iis\Development.ps1"

  # Use our retagged XConnect image.
  # Configure for a mounted license folder instead of using SITECORE_LICENSE.
  # Note: XConnect roles expect a folder with license.xml, not the file itself.
  xconnect:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-xconnect:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/xconnect
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xconnect:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_LICENSE_FOLDER}:c:\license
    environment: 
      SITECORE_LICENSE_LOCATION: c:\license\

  # Use our retagged XConnect Search Indexer image.
  # Configure for a mounted license folder instead of using SITECORE_LICENSE.
  xdbsearchworker:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-xdbsearchworker:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/xdbsearchworker
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xdbsearchworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_LICENSE_FOLDER}:c:\license
    environment: 
      SITECORE_LICENSE_LOCATION: c:\license\

  # Use our retagged Marketing Automation Engine image. 
  # Configure for a mounted license folder instead of using SITECORE_LICENSE.
  xdbautomationworker:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-xdbautomationworker:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/xdbautomationworker
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xdbautomationworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_LICENSE_FOLDER}:c:\license
    environment: 
      SITECORE_LICENSE_LOCATION: c:\license\

  # Use our retagged Cortex Processing Engine image.
  # Configure for a mounted license folder instead of using SITECORE_LICENSE.
  cortexprocessingworker:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-cortexprocessingworker:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/cortexprocessingworker
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cortexprocessingworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_LICENSE_FOLDER}:c:\license
    environment: 
      SITECORE_LICENSE_LOCATION: c:\license\

Any one faced this error.

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Type the following command in your PowerShell and tell us the output. `Write $env:SITECORE_LICENSE`. My guess is, you have this environment variable pointing to a network share. This is not going to work. This is also what the error message clearly tells you. 

Alternatively there is a `docker-compose.override.yml` file in play that you are not sharing with us. And that might be the source of the strange `c:\license:rw` path.

Comment: This command $env:SITECORE_LICENSE returns nothing. I have shared my docker-compose.override.yml file

Comment: Right., because you introduced your own. What does `$env:HOST_LICENSE_FOLDER` give you?

Comment: $env:HOST_LICENSE_FOLDER  gives the path of folder having 'license.xml' file (  like D:\Self\sitecore10apps\FirstAPP
)